# Why am I unable to import my app to urls.py?

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to import my app's views to urls.py but I keep getting a module not found error.I've tried diffirent formats for the import statements without success, also tried creating another project and a new app with pycharm but still getting module not found error.

**Installed apps**

```
    'milk.apps.MilkConfig',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from main.milk import views
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('milk/', include('milk.urls')),
    path('accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
    path('signup/', views.signup_view, name='signup'),
]
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

**Directory**

```
milkfolder
    -capri library root(virtual env)
    -main (project dir)
        __init__.py
        settings.py
        urls.py...etc
        -milk(app)
            __init__.py
            models.py
            urls.py
            views.py...etc
```

Would also like to know if there is an alternative to create user signup view that doesn't involve importing an app to main urls.py.

Comment: I'm a complete noob at this, but I've only ever created apps with one word name and installed them using that name. So I would add the app as 'milk' without the .apps.Config. Same thing re. from main.milk, I just say 'from milk ...' Could also try from . import views.

Comment: "So I would add the app as 'milk' without the .apps.Config"—there's [nothing wrong with `milk.apps.MilkConfig`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/applications/#configuring-applications). "Could also try from . import views"—OP isn't trying to import from `.`, though.

Answer (score 0):

This looks very unusual:

```
from main.milk import views
```

Why are you using `main` here? A typical Django import would look more like

```
from milk import views
```

Comment: Ive tried that but django cant find the app, and gives an unresolved reference error.

Comment: Ah, you've added a directory listing. Why is there a `main/` directory there? What's its purpose?

Comment: main is the name of the project dir

Comment: But why is it there? What's its purpose? Normally everything in your `main/` directory would be right in the `milkfolder/` directory.

Comment: Nevermind..The import now works fine when i tried using vscode with "from milk import views". No idea why though..milkfolder is the name of the folder I saved my entire work on desktop

Comment: The name of the top-level folder that contains everything is irrelevant. It could be called anything; it isn't part of the module name.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your Django version and if you put in INSTALLED_APPS `'milk.apps.MilkConfig'`, make sure you have in your `milk` app a file named `apps.py` with at least the following content:

```
# milk/apps.py
from django.apps import AppConfig


class MilkConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'milk'
```

Otherwise, just put `milk` in INSTALLED_APPS

For more information, please visit the [doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/applications/#configuring-applications)